# Magento 1.9 Calendar not displayed on customer registration page

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, calendar

I am using magento 1.9 for my website. I have enabled Javascript calendar in magento admin, but it is not displayed on customer registration page for Date of Birth field.

How should I enable it?